# JavaFX Stylesheet out off folder?

Tags: css, file, javafx, stylesheet

is it possible to set the Stylesheet file in JavaFX out of project (example : C:\Program Files\MyFolder).

Here's my code :

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("C:\\Program Files\\MyFile\\Style.css").toExternalForm());
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible, though I havent tried it yet. Check this out: http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/04/use-external-css-files-javafx/

Comment: this really should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. The link here provides an almost-complete answer, but it hiccups when the stylesheet is contained in a folder that has a space.

The right way to do it is like this:

```
String fontSheet = fileToStylesheetString( stylesheet.toFile() );
if ( fontSheet == null ) {
    //Do Whatever you want with logging/errors/etc.
} else {
    scene.getStylesheets().add( fontSheet );
}

public String fileToStylesheetString ( File stylesheetFile ) {
    try {
        return stylesheetFile.toURI().toURL().toString();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        return null;
    }
}
```